# Bigger received ts format video through vlc interface stream than original

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, vlc, mpeg-4, mpeg-2

I need to stream video files over UDP using MPEG-2 codec, so I figured it would be best to stream it on .ts container format rather than .mp4  only to convert it at the Client through the VLC interface, with the profile "MPEG-2 + MPGA (TS)".

Ok, so once I streamed it on .ts and saved it (converting with the same MPEG-2 profile, which is the only one that produces .ts format videos), I realized that the received clip was actually more than twice its original size. Also, the frame rate kept its value at 30 fps and its bitrate also increased by over 2.

However, when I streamed the same sequence on .mp4 to later convert it to .ts (through VLC), the original and transmitted videos were about the same size!

I measured its PSNR and VQMg to get more info and its average values were:

1. Streaming and converting on .ts

   > psnr: 32,54
   >
   > VQMg: 0,092
2. Streaming on .mp4 and converting on .ts

   > psnr: 12.77
   >
   > VQMg: couldnt measure it, BVQM crashed.

Well, I first thought the first process was too good to be true, but then I saw the second and thought it was too bad (I couldnt even measure its VQMg and frankly, I think the video wasnt that bad after I watched it).

Is it ok to keep streaming with the way I do with the first process or am I doing it wrong? And how can the received video be twice as bigger as the original?

I only know how to use VLC through it's interface, no prompt commands please.